# Tflearn, AxlexNet, ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (64, 277, 277, 3) for Tensor u'InputData/X:0', which has shape '(?, 227, 227, 3)'

Tags: python, tensorflow, tflearn

I am trying to used the example AlexNet (https://github.com/tflearn/tflearn/blob/master/examples/images/alexnet.py) with my own data, however I am getting the following error:

```
python alex_net.py 
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:111] successfully opened CUDA library libcublas.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:111] successfully opened CUDA library libcudnn.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:111] successfully opened CUDA library libcufft.so locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:111] successfully opened CUDA library libcuda.so.1 locally
I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:111] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.so locally
^[I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:951] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: GeForce GTX TITAN X
major: 5 minor: 2 memoryClockRate (GHz) 1.076
pciBusID 0000:05:00.0
Total memory: 11.92GiB
Free memory: 11.81GiB
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:972] DMA: 0 
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:982] 0:   Y 
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1041] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX TITAN X, pci bus id: 0000:05:00.0)
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1041] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX TITAN X, pci bus id: 0000:05:00.0)
---------------------------------
Run id: alexnet_oxflowers17
Log directory: /tmp/tflearn_logs/
---------------------------------
Training samples: 132162
Validation samples: 14685
--
--
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "alex_net.py", line 114, in <module>
    snapshot_epoch=False, run_id='alexnet_oxflowers17')
  File "/home/psxts3/.virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tflearn/models/dnn.py", line 188, in fit
    run_id=run_id)
  File "/home/psxts3/.virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tflearn/helpers/trainer.py", line 277, in fit
    show_metric)
  File "/home/psxts3/.virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tflearn/helpers/trainer.py", line 684, in _train
    feed_batch)
  File "/home/psxts3/.virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 717, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/home/psxts3/.virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 894, in _run
    % (np_val.shape, subfeed_t.name, str(subfeed_t.get_shape())))
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (64, 277, 277, 3) for Tensor u'InputData/X:0', which has shape '(?, 227, 227, 3)'
```

I am using cv2 to read in the images and resize them to 277 by 277 pixels, all of the images are then stored in an array, X, which has the shape of [146847, 277, 277, 3].
The labels are stored in multiple csv files and are read into an array, Y, and has shape of [146847, 5]. Each label has 5 different classes, ranging from 0 to 1 in 0.2 steps.

The network code is as follows:

```
net = input_data(shape=[None, 227, 227, 3])
net = conv_2d(net, 96, 11, strides=4, activation='relu')
net = max_pool_2d(net, 3, strides=2)
net = local_response_normalization(net)
net = conv_2d(net, 256, 5, activation='relu')
net = max_pool_2d(net, 3, strides=2)
net = local_response_normalization(net)
net = conv_2d(net, 384, 3, activation='relu')
net = conv_2d(net, 384, 3, activation='relu')
net = conv_2d(net, 256, 3, activation='relu')
net = max_pool_2d(net, 3, strides=2)
net = local_response_normalization(net)
net = fully_connected(net, 4096, activation='tanh')
net = dropout(net, 0.5)
net = fully_connected(net, 4096, activation='tanh')
net = dropout(net, 0.5)
net = fully_connected(net, num_classes, activation='softmax')
net = regression(net, optimizer='momentum', loss='categorical_crossentropy', learning_rate=0.001)
```

where the num_classes = 5.

```
model = tflearn.DNN(net, checkpoint_path='model_alexnet',
                max_checkpoints=1, tensorboard_verbose=2)
model.fit(X, Y, n_epoch=1000, validation_set=0.1, shuffle=True,
      show_metric=True, batch_size=64, snapshot_step=200,
      snapshot_epoch=False, run_id='alexnet_oxflowers17')
```

Any further information need please ask.

Comment: Note that 277 != 227

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As nessuno said in the first comment, you are feeding the wrong size image in to the graph. Change your first line to the following.

```
net = input_data(shape=[None, 277, 277, 3])
```